# Read another contract's storage without making a transaction?

Tags: smart-contracts

Is it possible for contract X to read the storage of contract Y without making a transaction?

I think I understand how I can make X call a function on Y using a callback pattern. But since I only want to read the storage of Y - and they are on the same ledger - the data should be readily available to X without making any transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an updated answer, views have been added when the [Hangzhou protocol](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/011_hangzhou.html#michelson-on-chain-views) was activated.

They are known as "On-chain views" and their usage with the various high level contract languages can be found searching this term.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for a contract X to access the storage of contract Y against Y's will. The main reason to forbid this is to prevent ticket steal. For contract Y, allowing contract X to read some part of the storage is typically done using [the view pattern of TZIP 4](https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-4/#view-entrypoints) but in the future [first-class views might be added to Michelson](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/2359).

Comment: It could be done through an explicit unpair which would protect against stealing tickets.